# the checkbox event is not triggerd?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, event-handling

i have created checkbox event maually.

```
chkCheckBox1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkCheckBox1_CheckedChanged);
```

this event is not triggered,in pageload i have put

```
(!page.ispostback)
{
}
```

so when i clik the check box it goes to the page load and not going to the evnt

```
protected void chkCheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ..........  
}
```

the checkbox event is not triggerd..

Answer (score 4):

Have you enabled AutoPostBack property on your control?

By default this is set to False when you add a checkbox control to your page.  Try setting it to true.

Comment: Did this solve your problem?  Let me know if you are still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Autopostback` property to **true**.

> chkCheckBox1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkCheckBox1_CheckedChanged);

You have to wire up this event on every call to the page so if you have put this inside of the `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` then put it outside.

Take a look at this article [Adding a dynamic control to a placeholder control and wire up the event](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/AddingADynamicControlToAPlaceholderControlAndWireUpTheEvent.aspx). It shows an extra step for making things totally dynamic but the principles stay the same for what you're after.

Grz, Kris.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the following event

protected void chkCheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   ..........
}

Set the checkbox **autopostback** property to TRUE